# How to validate the fields used in a visualforce page?

Tags: visualforce

[image]

how to validate the fields used in a visualforce page?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Required attribute of the inputfield vf tag

```
<apex:inputfield required="true" value="" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer,but i need to display first name is required,last name is required like this name need to mention and need to show at a time to show 2 errors when 2 fields is empty.when 1 field is empty need to show one error.

Answer (score 0):

you can show by custom way
Page

```
<apex:outputPanel id="showError" layout="blank" rendered="{!if(strCustomErrorMsg != '',true,false)}">
   <apex:outputText value="{!strCustomErrorMsg}" />
 </apex:output>
<apex:inputText value="{!objAcc.FirstName}"/>
<apex:inputText value="{!objAcc.LastName}"/>
 <apex:commandbutton action="{!Save}" rerender="showError"/>
```

Controller

```
public string strCustomErrorMsg {get;set;}

public void save(){
  strCustomErrorMsg = '';
  if(objAcc.FirstName == null || objAcc.FirstName == '')
    strCustomErrorMsg = 'First Name required';
  if(objAcc.FirstName == null || objAcc.FirstName == '')
    strCustomErrorMsg = strCustomErrorMsg + '<br/> Last Name required';
}
```

I have not tested this code, hope this will help you..

Comment: its not working.In save method i need to use pagereference.while all fields had given it need to move another page....

Comment: you can use common controller for the both the pages